# maven, how to skip a goal/plugin that is not found in pom

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a multi module project and I have a parent pom for all the modules. I want to write a tomcat plugin in only few of the sub modules and when I execute `mvn tomcat7:deploy`on my parent I get errors for the project that do not have tomcat plugin. Is there anyway that I can skip this in the modules that do not have tomcat module?

Thanks in Advance :)

**EDIT:**

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.mortbay.jetty, org.apache.maven.plugi
ns, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories
```

Comment: It would be great if you add the error messages on your question.

Comment: @JorgeCampos added the error to my question